# How can I use Regex to parse irregular CSV and not select certain characters

Tags: regex

I have to handle a weird CSV format, and I have been running into problems.  The string I have been able to work out thus far is

```
(?:\s*(?:\"([^\"]*)\"|([^,]+))\s*?)+?
```

My files are often broken and irregular, since we have to deal with OCR'd text which is usually not checked by our users.  Therefore, we tend to end up with lots of weird things, like a single " within a field, or even a newline character(which is why I am using Regex instead of my previous readLine()-based solution).  I've gotten it to parse most everything correctly, except it captures [,] [,].  How can I get it to NOT select fields with only a single comma?  When I try and have it not select commas, it turns "156,000" into [156] and [000]

The test string I've been using is

```
"156,000","",""i","parts","dog"","","Monthly "running" totals"
```

The ideal desire capture output is

```
[156,000],[],[i],[parts],[dog],[],[Monthly "running" totals]
```

I can do with or without the internal quotes, since I can always just strip them during processing.

Thank you all very much for your time.

Comment: What regex flavor are you using?

Comment: I'm parsing directly in C#, so .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV is indeed irregular and difficult to parse. I suggest you do 2 replacements first to your data.

```
// remove all invalid double ""
input = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<!,|^)""(?=,|$)|(?<=,)""(?!,|$)", "\"");

// now escape all inner "
input = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<!,|^)"(?!,|$)", @"\\\"");

// at this stage your have proper CSV data and I suggest using a good .NET csv parser
// to parse your data and get individual values
```

[Replacement 1 demo](https://regex101.com/r/fK7oE6/1)

[Replacement 2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/tC8cK4/1)